# in a Svelte Writable store, how can I set a different Type for getter/setter in Typescript/Svelte?

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit

In one of my projects, I am using SvelteKit, Tailwind CSS, and especially TypeScript.

During the development, I understood that I must use a writable store, instead of passing the props.

Everything works fine, but the typing system is not as dynamic as it should be.

---

**Let me explain,

 To make you understand, where I want to go,

 By oversimplifying my actual scenario:**

I have an array with child objects with the same shape, like this:

```js
[
  {
    id: "myUniqueId",
    type: "MyType",
    properties: {
      foo: "bar",
    },
  },
  {
    ...
  },
  {
    ...
  },
];
```

this array is passed inside the writable store like this:

```js
import { writable } from "svelte/store";
import { exampleArray } from "$lib/data/exampleData";
export const myAppStore = writable<TypeMyAppStore>([]);

myAppStore.set(exampleArray);
```

with this code, everything is right, even in typescript

but, now I want to make the user to explicitly,

to don't add the `id`, so the object becomes something like this:

```js
{
  type: "MyType",
  properties: {
    foo: "bar",
  },
},
```

the `id` will be added dynamically using `.set()` and `.update()`

```js
appStore.subscribe((value) => { 
  value.forEach((thisObj) => {
    thisObj.id = generateUniqueId();
  });
  appStore.set(value);
});
```

with this approach, I can basically add the IDs dynamically when the user pushes a new object inside my store.

the problem is in the IntelliSense autocompletion and typescript, because:

- the parameter input of the writable store, should NOT have `id`
- But the store itself, must have a id (a string)

the code and app is running fine,

but I need a way to make the writable store, accept only type without id, but in intellisense suggest the `id`.

if you think about it, we can say that:

- the "getter" should make the typescript suggest the type that includes `id`,
- the "setter" must accept only an array of objects that omit `id`.

if we want to talk about the same situation but in another context, is like this:

```js
function foo(input: TypeMyInput): TypeMyOuput {}
//This is literally what I want to implement in my svelte store,
//Accept one input with a certain type
// change that array using `.subscribe()`/`.set()`
// then make by svelte store, to think about another type (and not give errors anymore only if the type is not respected, and also give me autocompletion and intellisense)

//For now I solved only the input, but the output not.
// writable<TypeMyInput>([])
```

How we can do both (I mean without union type) in a way that can accept only one type, but return another type?

---

all the code above is not nearly my real-world code, is an oversimplified example for you.

**Remember**

- I am not asking about how I write the types (since I have experience in typescript/svelte-kit),

   But how I can make the svelte store writable and do the things I wrote before,

   Because is something new that isn't written in the docs,

   So I hope someone who had the same situation as me, answers this question.
- the code execution is right and working fine, don't focus on that (I mean all suggestions for improvements are accepted), but the problem is only inside the typescript part.

I hope you understand my situation.

if you still don't understand what I want, I can give you the link to my GitHub repo https://github.com/Laaouatni/laaCAD/blob/development/app/src/lib/Data/appStore/appStore.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at *custom stores* these allow you to create your own stores (that you can subscribe to with `$`) while adding some extra functionality.

For example this code

```
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

const createStore = <T extends { id: string }>() => {
  const store = writable<T[]>([]);

  return {
    subscribe: store.subscribe,
    add: (value: Exclude<T, 'id'>) => {
      const value_with_id = {
        ...value,
        id: crypto.randomUUID() as string
      };
      store.update(($store) => {
        $store.push(value_with_id);
        return $store;
      });
    }
  };
};

export default createStore;
```

does almost what you want:

- define a store of items (with id) for which the subscribed value included the `id`
- define an "add" method that forces you to only add items without id

I made it with an `add` function just because it feels weird that everytime you change the store you would change all ids ? (I wonder if this wouldn't also cause an infinite loop for that matter because you are changing all items everything an item changes?)
You also ask for a `setter` without id, but then use `.set` with values that have an id, which seems a bit strange :)

Comment: yeah, you are right, I got multiple times in an infinite loop. for now, I rechanged the type system, by using an optional `id?` because it turns out that even If the user setted his id... in subscribe/set I just replace his id. with this approach If I don't set id typescript doesn't complain, if I set id typescript doesn't complain, and I also have intellisense. for now, I used the length to not go in an infinite loop. basically, when the length changes I do the logic. still a bad approach, but is a work in progress. I have to used this approach since the array is inside a nested objects/array

Comment: I don't why I was thinking in the hard way, when there a simple way. sorry for the time you dedicated here, upvoted also. Maybe this solution will help others that had the same situation. thanks @stephane

Answer (score 1):

Stores, when used with `$`-syntax, behave like regular variables, variables can only have one type.
So I don't think you get around wrapping the value in an object.

Example:

```js
function dualTypedWritable<TGet, TSet>(
    initialValue: TSet,
    onSet: (newValue: TSet) => TGet,
) {
    const store = writable<TGet>(onSet(initialValue));
    return derived(store, storeValue => ({
        get value(): TGet { return storeValue; },
        set value(newValue: TSet) { store.set(onSet(newValue)); }
    }));
}
    
const items = dualTypedWritable(
    [{
        type: "MyType",
        properties: { foo: "bar" },
    }],
    newItems => newItems.map(item => ({
        id: Math.random().toString().slice(2),
        ...item,
    })),
);
```

Every access is then via `$items.value`.

Alternatively, you could use functions rather than a property with getter and setter.

Comment: in the end, I completely get around this problem by using a simple `id?`, I know it is not the best and most concise/severe type, but it is still the simplest way. thanks anyway for your solution, upvoted. I don't why I was thinking in the hard way, when there a simple way. thanks @brunnerh